# add link in Colorbox caption

Tags: navigation, javascript

In my gallery, what i write as image title is the caption of my image and that is great.
Now I would like to add a link (external url) to my caption, how can i do that?
I already try to write normal url and html a tag but is always ignored.

I see two option in Colorbox configuration related some link, i play a bit with that but I didn't really understand what i'm supposed to do with that

How did you do?

**EDIT: Add screenshots step by step adding link for title**

My Colorbox gallery is placed in custom 'Photo Gallery' Content type. Here there are a list of images with Alt and Title.
This images are automatically grouped thanks another view "Gallery Photo" which display the first image and then thanks to colorbox open all the other inside it as a gallery.

http://loungesquatt.com/drupal734

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: refer this tutorial- (http://www.zyxware.com/articles/3078/solved-drupal-drupal-colorbox-how-to-display-an-image-its-title-and-then-the-images-node-title-as-a-link-in-colorb)

Comment: thanks for the link. Do you think that technique can work for external link as well?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it with JQUERY,there is another way as patching colorbox,but by default color box dont support link as title

```
   $('#cboxTitle').html('<a href="yourlink.com">title</a>');
```

Comment: cool! thanks for the tip. So you mean to add that line in the img Title UI field? I try and it show me the code as caption

Comment: @GiorgiaSambrotta, you can inspect the element title and just need put its id in jquery selector, my code is a clue :)

Comment: i see! That is ok but it will be not very customizable from clients

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps given in this [tutorial](http://www.zyxware.com/articles/3078/solved-drupal-drupal-colorbox-how-to-display-an-image-its-title-and-then-the-images-node-title-as-a-link-in-colorb) and then add one extra field as shown in below snapshot.

[image]

Give your external link to this field as shown below

[image]

Final step would be to use **replacement pattern** for this field in **colorbox trigger** caption field along with the title.

[image]

[image]

**Sample output:**

[image]

I have tested it and its working.

Comment: wow! Thank you very much for your time. I'm going to try now :)

Comment: Mhmm i'm doing something wrong from the beginning because nothing really change to me. I create a view of content type 'Gallery Photo' then I make this view as Block. Is right or should be a page? then I create all the fields explained in the tutorial and yours field. Should I maybe do something more, obvious to you(but not to a beginner like me:) )?

Comment: Also: Adding Global:Custom Text field basically will give me the chance to add an external link as title, but Will be always the same link for all the caption? And every time need to be changed, admin need to change it from the view, not from the gallery in it self, is this correct?

Comment: You can give title to your external link using Replacement patterns. example: instead of using 'External link' as title you can replace it with '[title]' or any other. Where [title] is your replacement pattern.

Comment: ok! But I still don't see the title as link. Custom or not is still a plain text

Comment: can you please post the 'screenshot'? So that I can help you.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I edit and add all the info that I could add :)

Comment: Seems all good, please remove "==Global:Custom text" from Caption field. You only need to type **[nothing]**. See that in my last screenshot and check if it works.

Comment: nope, nothing really change.. I don't know what else I should check, it seems to me all the same of your and the tutorial info. Maybe something else, even before? How can I be sure that I'm modify exactly that field in my gallery colorbox?